# Set a focus on input field after alert in JavaScript error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set focus on a specific input field using JavaScript function.

Here is the coding:

```js
function checknag() {
  var x1 = document.getElementById('tsumnag').value;
  var x2 = document.getElementById('salenugsum').value;
  if (+x1 == +x2) {

    // here the button key 'hey' will be used as the text.
    $('#munshi_perc').focus();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input required class="urdu" onfocusout='checknag();' value="" type="text" />
<input required class="urdu" id="tsumnag" value="" type="text" />
<input required class="urdu" id="salenugsum" value="" type="text" />
<input required class="urdu" id="munshi_perc" value="" type="text" />
```

It just focuses, but I need alert and then focus on the input field.

---

### Update

The code below does not work:

```js
function checknag() {
  var x1 = document.getElementById('tsumnag').value;
  var x2 = document.getElementById('salenugsum').value;
  if (+x1 == +x2) {
    $.alert({
      title: 'Alert!',
      content: 'Please enter item name',
      onDestroy: function() {
        // here the button key 'hey' will be used as the text.
        $('#munshi_perc').focus();
      }
    });
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input required class="urdu" onfocusout='checknag();' value="" type="text" />
<input required class="urdu" id="tsumnag" value="" type="text" />
<input required class="urdu" id="salenugsum" value="" type="text" />
<input required class="urdu" id="munshi_perc" value="" type="text" />
```

Comment: Where is the alert? What is not working?

Comment: alert box not show there is error

Comment: @epascarello there is error $.alert is not function

Comment: So, what is the problem? The code works.

Comment: use `alert(' your message')` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert

Comment: Where there is no $.alert() in JQuery core. Sounds like you do not have a library....

Comment: Error alert box? I've last seen those in IE7...

Comment: @Teemu yes alert error and not focused on the input field

Comment: Configure your browser to not show error alert boxes, and read the error messages from the DevTools at Console tab.

Comment: dear it's not show alert and not focused on input field

Comment: function checknag(){
            var x1 = document.getElementById('tsumnag').value;
            var x2 = document.getElementById('salenugsum').value;
            if (+x1 == +x2) {
              $.alert({
                title: 'Alert!',
                content: 'Please enter item name',
                onDestroy: function() {
                  // here the button key 'hey' will be used as the text.
                  $('#munshi_perc').focus();
                }
              });


              return false;
            }
          }

Comment: Are you using a plugin called [`jquery-confirm`](https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/#getting-started)? Because you will need to have `jQuery.alert` defined in order to use it. jQuery does not come shipped with such a method. Make sure you follow the installation guide in their documentation.

Comment: no im not using any plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comments below your question:

> no im not using any plugin

So that is the problem. I guess you just pasted some code from somewhere and did not look at the dependencies.

Your code works if the [jQuery-Confirm](https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/#getting-started) plugin is loaded. So just add the CDNs used in the below snippet.

```js
function checknag() {
  var x1 = document.getElementById('tsumnag').value;
  var x2 = document.getElementById('salenugsum').value;
  if (+x1 == +x2) {
    $.alert({
      title: 'Alert!',
      content: 'Please enter item name',
      onDestroy: function() {
        // here the button key 'hey' will be used as the text.
        $('#munshi_perc').focus();
      }
    });
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.4/jquery-confirm.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.4/jquery-confirm.min.js"></script>

<input required class="urdu" onfocusout='checknag();' value="" type="text" />
<input required class="urdu" id="tsumnag" value="" type="text" />
<input required class="urdu" id="salenugsum" value="" type="text" />
<input required class="urdu" id="munshi_perc" value="" type="text" />
```

Comment: I think OP needs to understand how plugins (aka modules, extensions, mixins) work.

Comment: Probably... What do you suggest as an answer update?

Comment: Nothing... question should be closed as a "typo" since OP forgot to include a library.

Comment: I agree... So let's do that!